# Why was the doll from Annabelle so treasured?

Tags: plot-explanation, annabelle, the-conjuring-universe

Couple of instances that point to the unexplained & inexplicable importance of the doll sans as the conduit.

First, at the beginning, when John gives the doll as a gift to Mia, when she exclaims something on the lines of *"I've been looking for this for so long.
Where did you find it?" "Well, I have my means"*

Secondly, at the end, when an old women exclaims to a shop owner about the doll, saying that she wants to gift it to her daughter who is a nurse. 
The shop owner replies with something like *"Oh sure, that doll is a collector's item"*

Even before being turned into a conduit, the doll was hideous & scary. Why was it treasured so much in the movie(as a doll, not as a conduit by the cult)?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The real doll was a vintage Raggedy Ann doll (unlike the porcelain one used in the movie).  These dolls are collectible, and can fetch upwards of US$3,000.

And yes, old dolls are usually creepy looking.

Here's a webpage about their collectibility: [From Raggedy To Riches](http://www.cbsnews.com/news/from-raggedy-to-riches/)

In short, it's kinda like finding a 1952 Willie Mays Topps card.